# comparison of computer processing language vs protocol

Tags: http, programming-languages, machine-code

how can explain the diference between programming languge and protocol?, 
can protocol have extension?

we know that machines communicate with protocol, but they can also do so with expressive language.

so, I think the difference between these two is unclear. also, the references for defining these two are not clear.
so maybe protocol is superset of language, eg: 
protocol equ communication language?, 
assembly equ machine language?, 
css equ styling language?,

can any body do explain what is a protocol compared to language?

Comment: Philosophically speaking, these two things do indeed look rather similar. In practice though, one is a description and one is an implementation tool. I'm not sure how fruitful a detailed analysis of the difference would be. Are you trying to engage in a philosophical debate, or are you generally confused about the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) (programming languages are a subset of those) is a *set of strings* that are valid in that language. For a language to be useful, it also has to have *semantics*, i.e. what does a string in the language mean.

For example, `print('hello')` is a valid string in the language Python and `{ "name": "zukerman" }` is a valid string in the language JSON.

On the other hand, a protocol describes *how machines communicate* with each other using messages. A protocol can define what messages can be sent when, what are the roles of the machines (e.g. client and server), etc. A protocol also defines the format of messages, which is a language, though it's not commonly called that.

For example, you can't really say that `GET /index.html HTTP/1.0` is a valid string in the protocol HTTP, even though it's a valid HTTP client request.

If you're asking specifically about programming languages, then those are languages whose semantics *describes computations*. Protocols in general don't do that, though some specific protocols do, e.g. [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) protocols.

Comment: by saying "describes how" you mean "process how"?. so protocol is a processor? and language is not a processor?. also, rest protocol have some semantics.

Comment: @zukermanyoav Protocol doesn't actually do anything, it's not an application. So I don't see how could you consider it to be a processor.

Comment: but. if we configure the protocol with set of rules. its same as we configure the processor. eventualy, these two end up in machine code. so protocol process something.

Comment: @zukerman A protocol is typically a *description* written in English (or another human language). It doesn't do anything. The steps the protocol describes need to be implemented in a programming language before it does anything.

Comment: in my opinion. programming language doesnt do anyting until implemnted in machine code. so language and protocol are both rules in different pardigms.

Comment: @zukerman That's why I commented that the distinction is somewhat philosophical. If you could compile the English language description into machine code, the difference would be mostly mood. But you can't. Your implementation will also need to consider more issues than just what the protocol describes. Also, image the programming language we're talking about *is* machine code.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction is a matter of degree.

Consider the security procedures at a major bank. Every morning the first employe to appear moves a certain potted plant to a subtly different location to signal all other employees "It's okay, there is **NOT** a criminal gang lurking in the back office trying to kidnap the first two employees to show up and to get them to open the four-eyes safe" (or so I've read in thriller novels). When the second employee arrives and the plant has *not* been moved, they know to call the police immediately.

This is a protocol. It uses well-specified signals to express well-specified meanings, but rather few of them (only two different meanings).

Now compare this to the use of the English language between two employees to coordinate their work, or to chat about their personal lives. This also uses signals to express meanings, but the spectrum of what can be said and understood is infinitely richer and more complicated.

That, in a nutshell, is the difference between a protocal and a language. Restricted languages, such as the one used by international airline pilots when communication with air traffic control, are closer to mere protocols than normal language is. Very complicated protocols, such as big programming languages, are nearer to being languages than very simple ones. Where to draw the line between the two, as always, is ultimately a matter of opinion.

Comment: Protocols are expressed via language. Protocols themselves aren't the "signals", only the ordering of them, and what they mean.